can't access to the aws cloud9 ide
aws cloud 9
hello , when i want to access to the aws cloud9  this page appeard even if i set up already the payement method
I already tried some resources like aws cloud watch the cli also without any problem so most likely the problem isn't in the payement method (Btw i know that i have altrenatives but i just want to know the problem )
im in the region us-east-1
i thought its connexion so i switched it also the region , i dont think its a matter of payement method

From How to migrate from AWS Cloud9 to AWS IDE Toolkits or AWS CloudShell | AWS DevOps & Developer Productivity Blog:

After careful consideration, we have made the decision to close new customer access to AWS Cloud9, effective July 25, 2024. AWS Cloud9 existing customers can continue to use the service as normal.

It would appear that your AWS Account did not previously use Cloud9, so it is not available for you to use.
